# Set multiple sizes of text in a single legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to set multiple sizes of text in a single legend.

```
plot(1, 1)
legend("topleft", 
       legend=c("fruit", "apples", "oranges", "vegetables", "cucumber", "peppers"), 
       cex=0.8,
       pch=c(19, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA),
       col=c("red", "white", "white", "green", "white", "white"), 
       pt.cex=1)
```

[image: legendallsamesize]

I'd like the "apples," "oranges," "cucumber," and "peppers" to be a smaller size.

I can set different sizes of points in the following way:

```
plot(1, 1)
legend("topleft", 
       legend=c("fruit", "apples", "oranges", "vegetables", "cucumber", "peppers"), 
       cex=0.8,
       pch=c(19, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA),
       col=c("red", "white", "white", "green", "white", "white"), 
       pt.cex=c(1, NA, NA, 0.8, NA, NA))
```

But if I try to set the text size in a similar way, I get a warning, and it creates the legend twice in a strange way.

```
plot(1, 1)
legend("topleft", 
       legend=c("fruit", "apples", "oranges", "vegetables", "cucumber", "peppers"), 
       cex=c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.8),
       pch=c(19, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA),
       col=c("red", "white", "white", "green", "white", "white"), 
       pt.cex=c(1, NA, NA, 0.8, NA, NA))
```

[image: badlegend]

I am pretty sure my problem stems from not understanding what kind of input legend wants from cex.  I also realize I could probably call `legend()` twice, and use `text()` to insert my text, but that seems likely to be time-consuming and messy.

Comment: Since `legend` is having a hard time with `cex`, one option might be to change font weight: `text.font=c(2,3,3,2,3,3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you supply multiple values of `cex` in the legend call, it draws a legend for each (unique?) cex-value.

As @MrFlick suggests, you can use different fonts to create hierarchy. Here's a solution using text. By writing output of the legend call to `a`, we can easily re-use the calculated positions for the text labels and add text in different pointsizes with only 1 extra line:

```
plot(1, 1)

labs = c("fruit", "apples", "oranges", "vegetables", "cucumber", "peppers")

# add legend with white (invisible text) and store text positions in 'a'
a=legend("topleft", 
       legend=labs, 
       cex=1.0,
       text.col='white',
       pch=c(19),
       col=c("red", "white", "white", "green", "white", "white"))

# draw text labels at calculated positions
text(a$text$x, a$text$y, lab=labs, cex=c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.8), pos=4, offset=c(0,0.1))
```

Comment: +1 Nice to learn that `legend()` (like `hist()`, `barplot()`, et al.) has such a useful return value.

Comment: Agreed, @JoshO'Brien!  This solution did exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!

Comment: the `cex` argument in `?legend` references `title.cex` and `pt.cex` the latter can be found in the documentation, but title.cex doesn't seem to be a valid argument for legend. furthermore, cex in the source code for legend seems to be recycled in the chuck of code that deals with the legend title. Is this missing title.cex a mistake by rcore or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right! `title.cex` is missing from the source code. Of course there's a [workaround](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-April/276625.html), but it would be much easier to have a working `title.cex`!